# Why is the default word-wrap/overflow behavior different for inline vs inline-block elements?

Tags: html, css, display

Why do inline elements overflow but inline-block elements wrap to the next line? From what I understand inline-block is just inline but with editable height and width properties, but in this example the wrapping behavior is different. Is there anywhere I can find more information about this? I can't find any documentation describing this behavior.

If I change the word-wrap behavior to "break-word" for the containing div then the behavior is identical.

Example:
[image: example of inline block overflowing and inline-block wrapping]

[image: Edit inline vs inline-block word-break/overflow]

```
export default function App() {
  const arr = new Array(50).fill("inline");
  const arr2 = new Array(50).fill("inline-block");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((text) => (
        <div className="inline-div">{text}</div>
      ))}
      {arr2.map((text) => (
        <div className="inline-block-div">{text}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.inline-div {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}

.inline-block-div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
}

.App {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `inline` and `inline-block` differ in lots of ways. One important way in this case is that `inline-block` elements generate an [*atomic*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#atomic-inline) box, while the box that an `inline` element generates isn't atomic. The CSS Display Level 3 specification says:

> **atomic-inline**: An inline-level box that is replaced (such as an image) or that establishes a new formatting context (such as an inline-block or inline-table) and cannot split across lines (as inline boxes and ruby containers can).

Now the important concept here is [soft wrap opportunities](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#soft-wrap-opportunity). This is quite a complex area with lots of different rules for different languages, but only [one rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#ref-for-soft-wrap-opportunity%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A1) matters for the purpose of the question:

> For Web-compatibility there is a soft wrap opportunity before and after each replaced element or other atomic inline, even when adjacent to a character that would normally suppress them, such as U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE.